# Multiplas linhas de texto ou código com o método ".html()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Ao utilizar o método de jQuery [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) para aplicar múltiplas linhas de texto ou código HTML a um elemento, o mesmo falha com erro:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/5G5KP/)

```
$(function(){
     $( '.qualquerClasse' ).html( ' conteúdo de 3 linhas de código: uma
         Duas
         Três' 
     );
});
```

Vai gerar o erro:

> Error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

## Pergunta

Como proceder para aplicar múltiplas linhas entre as aspas?

Comment: Já tentou jogar tudo numa `string` só?

Comment: Olá Thiago, não se esqueça de formatar códigos postados, na tela de edição você só precisa selecionar o código e clicar no botão `{}` (ou pressionar o atalho `Ctrl`+`K`)

Comment: Se você estiver precisando fazer isso seguidamente, pode valer a pena conferir um esquema de templates como o [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com).

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda. Estou me familiarizando com as funções do stackoverflow ( e também do jQuery kkk), Fabrício Matté sem palavras, respondeu de imediato e com alternativas fantásticas. Vou verificar qual funciona melhor e depois comentarei mais. Zuul valeu pela edição e formatação .

Comment: @elias, já era uma pessoa antenada nas melhores formas de desenvolvimento web na êpoca, 11 mêses atrás, parabéns cara! Template engines era realmente o que precisava, mas na êpoca nem percebi isso; 2 mêses depois descobri e fiz um projeto com node.js, express.js e jade.js ficou bom, no entanto, a melhor forma que achei, e que uso atualmente, é o [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), aprendi a forma correta de instalar e usar assistindo o [curso do Jesus condé](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEtcGQaT56cgHfdvGguisToK90z321pRl), não usei mais template engine coloquei os conteúdos nos arrays.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JavaScript não permite caracteres de quebra de linhas literais dentro de strings.

Existem várias formas de contornar o problema.

Caso você realmente queira quebras de linha dentro da string, use `\n`:

```
 $( '.qualquerClasse' ).html( 'conteúdo de 3 linhas de código: uma \n Duas \n Três' );
```

Porém note que caracteres de quebra de linha dentro do HTML por padrão não são renderizadas (espaços colapsados) a menos que esteja dentro de um elemento cujo valor computado da propriedade CSS `white-space` seja `pre`/`pre-wrap`/`pre-line`. Caso contrário (na maioria dos casos) é necessário utilizar `<br>` para forçar uma quebra de linha visível.

Caso você deseje quebrar o texto em várias linhas para deixá-lo mais legível, é possível concatenar ou utilizar um array:

```
 $( '.qualquerClasse' ).html(
     ' conteúdo de 3 linhas de código: uma'
     + 'Duas'
     + 'Três'
 );
 //ou
 $( '.qualquerClasse' ).html([
     ' conteúdo de 3 linhas de código: uma',
     'Duas',
     'Três'
 ].join(''));
```

Claro que podes adicionar `\n` ou `<br>` conforme necessário nestas strings.

---

Também existe uma forma, não padrão, de "escapar" as quebra de linha colocando um `\` logo antes da quebra de linha literal:

```
$( '.qualquerClasse' ).html( ' conteúdo de 3 linhas de código: uma\
     Duas\
     Três'
);
```

Esta sintaxe não é padrão, mas tem um suporte muito bom. Porém, alguns browsers mantém os caracteres de quebra de linha dentro da string enquanto outros o descartam, portanto esta forma é um pouco inconsistente. Outro problema é que se adicionar qualquer caractere após o `\`, até mesmo um caractere de espaço, irá gerar um erro de sintaxe já que a quebra de linha não mais estará sendo escapada.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté oi! Se juntares _template strings_ a resposta fica modernizada :)

Answer (score 4):

So para complementar: recomendo o uso de [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/), um pre-processador de javascript (do mesmo modo que SASS/LESS pre-processam CSS).

Cofeescript oferece uma sintaxe muito mais conveniente e legivel. Uma das muitas vantagens e' a possibilidade de definir strings multi-line:

```
mobyDick = "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago --
  never mind how long precisely -- having little
  or no money in my purse, and nothing particular
  to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail
  about a little and see the watery part of the
  world..."
```

Ou com `"""` para manter a formatacao/indentacao:

```
html = """
       <strong>
         cup of coffeescript
       </strong>
       """
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma simples, mas não muito recomendada por facilitar o erro é simplesmente escapar a quebra de linha com uma barra **\**

```
 $( '.qualquerClasse' ).html( ' conteúdo de 3 linhas de código: uma\
     Duas\
     Três' 
 );
```

Mas a forma mais recomendada, que evita erros e não atrapalha a minificação do código para produção é a mostrada pelo [Fabrício Matté](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1944/fabricio-matte) aqui.

Comment: Interessante resposta, por apontar o motivo de ser algo não recomendado.

Answer (score 1):

### ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) e os Template literals (Template strings)

Os "templates literals" tem suporte em:

- Chrome 41+
- Edge 12+
- Firefox 34+
- Safari 9+
- WebView Android 41+
- Node.js 4+

Eles suportam quebra de linhas, o que facilita muito a "digitação", exemplo:

```js
$(function(){
   $( '.qualquerClasse' ).html( ` conteúdo de 3 linhas de código: uma
       Duas
       Três` );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre class="qualquerClasse"></pre>
```

Eles suportam bem mais do que quebras de linhas, ele é um esquema de "template", podendo passar variáveis assim `${var1} teste ${var2}`, por exemplo:

```js
var x = 3, y = 100;

console.log(`O x é ${x}
e o y é ${y}`);
```

Seria equivalente a:

```js
var x = 3, y = 100;

console.log('O x é ' + x + '\ne o y é ' + y);
```

Além de variáveis ele também suporta operações, por exemplo:

```js
var x = 3, y = 100;

console.log(`${x}+${y} = ${x + y} e
5 * ${x} + 1 = ${5 * x + 1}.`);
```

Seria equivalente a:

```js
var x = 3, y = 100;

console.log(x + '+' + y + ' = ' + (x + y) + ' e\n5 * ' + x + ' + 1 = ' + (5 * x + 1) + '.');
```