# Como quebrar strings em mais de uma linha sem concatenar?

Tags: javascript, tipagem

Sempre que precisa escrever algo muito logo em uma string no Javascript eu preciso concatenar, algo como:

```
var str = 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar' +
          'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar' +
          'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar' +
          'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar' +
          'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar'
;
```

No entanto ter que criar adicionar aspas (`"`) ou apostrofo `'`, é possivel quebrar uma string sem precisar concatenar?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) e [Accept Your Own Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)

Comment: Duplicada? -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4000/129

Comment: @Sergio Acredito que sim, só não encontrei a outra por causa do título.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/508279/1518921) é possível usando o backslash

Isto:

```
var str = "foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar";
```

Irá resultar em:

> foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar

Isto:

```
var str = "foo\
bar";
```

Irá resultar em:

> foobar

Para quebrar também as linhas do "valor" será necessário usar `\n` e `\` em seguida:

```
var str = "foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \n\
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar";
```

Comment: você mesmo cria o post e você mesmo responde em menos de 10 minutos? rs

Comment: @RafaelAcioly na verdade não, se você notar no momento de criar uma pergunta existe um checkbox pra você abrir um campo de resposta, isto serve pra quando queremos apenas agregar conteúdo novo e é uma pratica normal dos sites da SE, veja este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer -- Infelizmente já tive 2 perguntas com votos negativos porque alguns usuários acham que está pratica é errada :( infelizmente poucos leem a Central de ajuda -- Obrigado pelo upvote!!