# String multilinha com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com uma pequena string para exibir em JavaScript, porém depois de muito tentar, aprendi que se houver enter no meio do trecho de string a mesma não será exibida. Alguém pode me explicar se existe uma forma de organizar o código sem impossibilitar a exibição.

Segue o codigo:

```
function outros(){
   var exibir;
   exibir = '<input type= "checkbox" name="st[]" value="Penicilina">Penicilina <br> <input name="st[]"  value="Contraste" type="checkbox">Contraste <br>';

   elexibir= document.getElementById('teste1');
   elexibir.innerHTML= exibir;
  }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Multiplas linhas de texto ou código com o método ".html()"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4000/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento dei uma pesquisada rápida e tmb não tinha encontrado =]

Comment: @Brunno não precisa deletar a sua resposta, na verdade ela tem coisa a mais, sobre o ES6 (o que poderia ser feito na pergunta mais antiga), mas a dica que lhe dei é para futuras perguntas, eu mesmo dupliquei sem querer, isto é normal, a instrução ali é mesmo para as proximas vezes, agora fica a seu critério restaurar ou responder novamente :D, afinal de contas é bem interessante para a comunidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `\` no final para escapar a linha:

```
var suaString = "primeira linha \
                 segunda linha";
```

Com ECMAScript 6 você pode utilizar assim:

```
var suaString = `primeira linha
                 segunda linha`;
```

Comment: Um exemplo com seu [código](https://jsfiddle.net/w96p5ntc/) =]

Comment: Isto já foi perguntando em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4000/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88330/3635, recomendo que pesquise se já existe resposta e marque a pergunta como duplicata ao invés de responder, pois se não ficará vários conteudos repetidos e espalhados.